# Detecting JIT Optimizations or missed Optimizations

Tags: c#, .net, clr, jit, micro-optimization

The .NET CLR JIT will; to my understanding; try to optimize code using patterns such as **Method Inlining**, **Loop Unrolling**, etc... In the case of Method Inlining this would not be performed for reasons such as the following:

- Methods that are greater than 32 bytes of IL will not be inlined.
- Virtual functions are not inlined.
- Methods that have complex flow control will not be in-lined. Complex flow control is any flow control other than if/then/else; in this case, switch or while.
- Methods that contain exception-handling blocks are not inlined, though methods that throw exceptions are still candidates for inlining.
- If any of the method's formal arguments are structs, the method will not be inlined.
- Etc...

My question is... Is there any way to detect what the JIT Optimization process is deciding to skip for these or other reason?

My thinking is that, I want to know what areas of code may need to be restructured to ensure I can take advantange of JIT optimizations.

Comment: I don't think so... BUT in the future this might become possible with Roslyn

Comment: You could debug the jitted native code, but all that'll show you is what the jitter decided to do on that particular machine at that particular time. Presumably the jitter could choose to make a different decision in different circumstances.

Comment: Also, why worry about the implementation details of what the jitter is doing? There are all kinds of reasons for good/bad performance. Benchmark your code: if it's fast enough then leave it alone; if it's not fast enough then tweak it until it is. (And if, *at that point*, you need to examine the jitted code and try to determine what the jitter is doing then so be it.)

Comment: nit all versions of the JIT apply the same optimization there are some differences between the x86 and the x64 / IA64 JIT, sou the only way currently would be to debug the native code that is generated by the  JIT like @LukeH mentioned above.

Comment: @Yahia, Roslyn doesn't try to do anything like this. At least not in its current (CTP) form.

Comment: Thanks LukeH/Kolja... In my case nanoseconds count, I am digging deep to find every nanosecond I can. To the larger point about machine-for-machine optimizations, your point is valid. In this case, I'm trying to identify those points where the JIT would never optimize, without regard to the hardware architecture (Ex. method has try-catch block, method is too large, etc...). Any tips on tools/docs I can use to review JIT'ed native code?

Comment: If you want the information bad enough to use the [profiler api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384493(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you can register for JIT events and monitor the [JITInlining callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232601(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can run your application on your own build of `CoreCLR` and gather all statistics you want. You can examine [clrconfigvalues.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/inc/clrconfigvalues.h) and enable any flag you want to get any related information (for example JitDump, using `set COMPLUS_JitDump` command in command prompt)

It's not quite easy, but it's possible.